# Chrome Dev Tools - Code Coverage during navigation

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

The new code coverage feature is really awesome, but it can only test one page.

Obviously noone has a site where you can see all abstractions and modules at once. This might be the case on SPAs, though.

So the question is:

**Is there a possibility to capture the information across multiple sites during navigation?**

Tested in Chrome 63.0.3239.132

Comment: Just use the record button, and navigate freely between pages/sites, it will automatically record the page.

Comment: @GideonPyzer Can you confirm this is still the case? I remember this being true but couldn't get it working yesterday.

Comment: @JamesS Assuming I understood the question correctly, this is a gifv of the Coverage tool automatically recording the stats everytime I go to another page. https://i.imgur.com/Hcil53b.gifv

Comment: @GideonPyzer Ah. Yes. That's what I'm seeing now, too. Before it wouldn't refresh the files when you go to new pages. Basically what is sounds like denns is expecting now. I've confirmed with the Chrome team that this was recently "fixed" and now it refreshes file coverage when you visit a new page.

Comment: long story short: it used to be like this but now it isn't anymore ... i don't get the decision to switch to the "one-page-only-coverage". thx for the efforts!! should i answer it myself or does any of you want the reputation for the correct answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. Unfortunately it sucks a lot - it - does not save state between pages/ sub-pages: osx + chrome version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit). For now it's just toy to play, but not (yet) tool for production.